# Arrow Function Not Working In Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript, html

My arrow function does not work inside a ternary operator and also it gives me no error in the console

## Below Is My Code

> The Objects in the Holders Array Are Html Elements

```
const Holders =
    [
        {
            name: accountHolder,
            target: accountHelper
        },
        {
            name: helpHolder,
            target: helpContainer
        }
    ]
const holderbg = 'rgba(128,128,128,.1)'
document.querySelector('html').onclick = (event) => {
    Holders.map(holder => {
        holder.name.getAttribute('role') == event.target.getAttribute('role') ?
            // The Arrow Function Does Not Work But The Code Runs When It is not in the function
            // replacing ()=>{} with just holder.name.style.backgroundColor = holderbg works 
            () => {
                holder.name.style.backgroundColor = holderbg
                holder.target.classList.remove('hide')
            }

            :
            // The Arrow Function Does Not Work But The Code Runs When It is not in the function
            // replacing ()=>{} with just holder.name.style.backgroundColor = 'initial' works 
            () => {
                holder.name.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'
                holder.target.classList.add('hide')
            }


    })

}
```

Comment: You are declaring functions, not executing them

Comment: You mean to wrap everything on extra parenthesis and then invoke the result with `()`, for example: `(x%2 ? () => 'odd' : () => 'even')()`

Comment: Please see [ask]. It's not clear to me what you are actually tying to do. I don't see any benefit of using arrow functions or `.map()` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you are just declaring the arrow functions here, they are not being called anywhere.

To call them, you can store the returned function in variable then call it.

```js
document.querySelector('html').onclick = (event) => {
    Holders.map(holder => {
        const func = holder.name.getAttribute('role') == event.target.getAttribute('role') ?
            () => {
                holder.name.style.backgroundColor = holderbg
                holder.target.classList.remove('hide')
            }

            :
            () => {
                holder.name.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'
                holder.target.classList.add('hide')
            }

        func() // called here


    })

}
```

In the above code, the references to the functions will be created in every event call.
So better way is to save the function in variables like this

```js
const show = () => {
    holder.name.style.backgroundColor = holderbg
    holder.target.classList.remove('hide')
}

const hide = () => {
    holder.name.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'
    holder.target.classList.add('hide')
}

document.querySelector('html').onclick = (event) => {
    Holders.map(holder => {
        holder.name.getAttribute('role') == event.target.getAttribute('role')
            ? show()
            : hide()

    })

}
```

**Side note** - the `map` function used in the code is not being used as its application because `map` returns a transformed array according to the function passed. In this code, the function is returning `undefined` and also the result is not being stored. Consirder replacing it with `forEach`

Comment: dntdv, but why map?

Comment: @NinaScholz Well, the asker knows that. The answer resolves the problem directly asked in the question by the asker.

Comment: @NinaScholz Anyway, I have added a side note in the answer.

Comment: @ShivamSingla So you're saying i should replace map with forEach??
I don't understand why
But i get the same results when i replace map with forEach so is there any reason i should forgo the earlier for the latter???

Comment: @FreduahGideon there is nothing wrong using `map`, but there are semantics for `map` function that it returns a transformed array. But actually, you not doing any transformation, you are just looping on the array. An other reader of your code may be confused. Read [this](https://festack.blogspot.com/2018/09/javascript-array-map-filter-and-reduce.html) clear idea of `map`, `filter`, `reduce`.

Answer (score 5):

You have to execute the function you declared:

```
(() => {
            holder.name.style.backgroundColor = holderbg
            holder.target.classList.remove('hide')
        })()
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much 
Your Answer Helped Me.

I just don't know who is deliberately downvoting any reaction towards my post.
An Upvote to mine will help me just as i've done to your's

Comment: Glad that it helped. Don't worry about downwote bashing. The goal is to help each other and not the reputation. ;o)

Comment: Exactly @monkey-0001, but they should state the reason to do so, so that we can improve our answer or get to know what did we do wrong.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Maybe this people will learn some day.

Comment: Short and sweet! Thanks @monkey-0001 and @freduah-gideon!